# Cannot connect to AWS RDS postgres from EKS cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I am trying to connect to the RDS Postgres database from the EKS Kubernetes cluster and pod that is running the NestJS app with Typeorm.

EKS cluster and Postgres RDS are not in the same VPC, but the RDS instance is publicly available.

I used the RDS instance endpoint together with the other credentials and apply as environment variables for the app deployment

Connection from the pgAdmin works fine but when the pod is started I get the following error.

```
[Nest] 1  - 08/11/2023, 10:29:43 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] no pg_hba.conf entry for 
host "18.193.43.189", user "postgres", database "development", no encryption
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.193.43.189", user "postgres", database 
"development", no encryption
```

Here is the configuration for TypeOrm

```
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
    type: process.env.DB_TYPE as any,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    migrations: ['dist/**/database/migration/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    subscribers: ['dist/**/*.subscriber/{.ts,.js}'],
    migrationsRun: true,
    synchronize: true,
    uuidExtension: 'pgcrypto',
    schema: 'public',
    logging: process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true',
    migrationsTableName: 'florence_migration',
    namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
    ssl: false,
    options: { encrypt: false },
  }),
```

Here is my configuration for the RDS postgres

[image]
I have also inbound security group attached to the vpc
[image]

Comment: The error indicates an issue with authentication. Connectivity looks fine. I would highly advise against a public accessible database, especially with an open security group such as that one.

Comment: The server is unwilling to accept connections' which don't use SSL.  The client is either unable or unwilling to use SSL, or it does try SSL but that fails (in which, there should be a second error message, preceding the one you show)